# Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, option-type

I'm trying to create a simple filter app that filters the displayed image upon a button press.

```
 @IBAction func applyFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Create an image to filter
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image)

    // Create a random color to pass to a filter
    let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]

    // Apply a filter to the image
    let filteredImage = inputImage.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)

    // Render the filtered image
    let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent())

    // Reflect the change back in the interface
    photoImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)

}
```

I keep getting the error:

> Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm a Swift beginner.

Comment: You *have to* learn about Optionals, it's a key concept in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Answer (score 5):

An UIImageView does not always have an UIImage in its image property.

you should check before :

```
guard let img = photoImageView.image else { return }
let inputImage = CIImage(image: img)
```

Answer (score 4):

As Eric said, you should learn about optionals. In this case, if we look at the [UIImage init](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithCGImage:), we see that it can return nil if the method fails. As such, you have to make sure the UIImage is created successfully first

```
if let myImage = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage){
    photoImageView.image = myImage
}
```